# Mailgun Mailing List Address Bounced

Tags: python, mailgun

I have setup a mailing list via Mailgun, newsletter@example.com. When I send a message to this address with my Mailgun API key, the message is delivered to all of the members of the mailing list.

**Core Issue:** Mailgun also attempts to deliver the message to newsletter@example.com itself, which is an email address that doesn't exist, resulting in the below error in our logs each day

```
Failed: morningalert@example.com → newsletter@example.com 'Morning Report: 2017-05-12' Not delivering to previously bounced address
```

I could simply ignore this, but it does put a skew on our analytics and makes it difficult for us to notice meaningful errors since it shows a bounce every time. How can I address this so we do not cause this bounce error when sending to our mailing list? My (poorly written) Python code is below. Thank you!

```
def standard_message(key, to, from_email, from_name, subject, body, delivery_time=False, replyto=False):
    url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/tradedefender.com/messages"
    auth = ("api", key)
    data =  {"from": from_name + " <" + from_email + ">",
            "to": to,
            "subject": subject,
            "text": body}

    if(delivery_time != False):
        data["o:deliverytime"] = delivery_time

    if(replyto != False):
        data["h:Reply-To"] = replyto

    response = requests.post(url, auth=auth, data=data)

    if("200" in str(response)):
        return(True)
    else:
        raise Exception(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you double checked you don't have that email address in your database as a subscriber? I don't see why Mailgun would be trying to deliver to newsletter@example.com.

Failing that, you could try the “Suppressions” tab of the Control Panel to manually unsubscribe the email address:

https://app.mailgun.com/app/suppressions/tradedefender.com/unsubscribes

Comment: I did check that and didn't find it in any of our mailing lists. I didn't think to do that though, so good suggestion.